# isInvalid prop doesn't work for a custom component in Form Control - react-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

For the code below,

```js
<Form.Group>
  <Form.Control>
    isInvalid
    as={
      forwardRef(() => (<div>Report</div>))
    }
  <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">Invalid Report</Form.Control.Feedback>
</Form.Group>
```

The `Feedback` is **not activated** even though the `Form.Control` has the `isInvalid` prop set to true. I've noticed that it only happens if I pass a custom component using `forwardRef()`.

Is there any other way I can pass a custom control component so that the error classes are added to it?

Problem recreation here - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-demo-forked-5jdpn?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have the exact same issue with other npm components.